# Java Pattern of 1 row odd and 1 row even

Tags: java

I want to print a pattern like :

[image: This is Required pattern]

Till now i  have been able to achieve only for odd numbers like :

```
1 
3 5 7
```

-

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = kb.nextInt();
while (num % 2 == 0 || num < 0) {
    num = kb.nextInt();
}
int odd = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i += 2) {
    String a = "";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        a = odd + " ";
        odd += 2;
        System.out.print(a);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I am a beginner and new learner. please help

Comment: Maybe you swapped the 3 and the 4 in the pattern? I cannot see a logic in it...

Comment: I don't even get the pattern. There seems to be no real logial way to get it. If it is an assignment, then you should probably include the description

Comment: Aside from what @Oneiros said, shouldn't the 19 be 18? Edit: Nevermind, I see the pattern now.

Comment: @Jorge.V care to explain the pattern?

Comment: What input number is supposed to produce the example pattern in the picture?

Comment: I *think* he wants to alternate between a line of odds and a line of pairs while increasing the lenght in one on every line change. @OP confirm?

Comment: @Jorge.V in that case the last line doesn't work as 2 is an even number in a line of odds

Comment: @XtremeBaumer My money is on that being a typo, and same for some lines having the same amount of numbers.

Comment: The logic to me is that every second line is odd and every second line is even, numbers are added to a line until you have two numbers that are larger than the largest number in the previous line, then you print it and start on a new line.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson 4th line should've 4 elements then

Comment: No, 8 and 10 is larger than 7, then 11 and 13 is larger than 10 and so on.

Comment: What is your theory for the last 2 then?

Comment: That it is a cut off 21. This is in many ways a poorly written question. _Edit_ And now I realise this means there are three numbers that are larger in that row so my theory fails!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the expected result since that pattern is not clear, however this might be what you're looking for:

```
int evenCounter = 1;
int oddCounter = 2;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   boolean even = (i % 2 == 0);
   for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
      System.out.print((even ? evenCounter : oddCounter) + " ");
      evenCounter += even ? 2 : 0;
      oddCounter +=  even ? 0 : 2;
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Result:

```
1 
2 4 
3 5 7 
6 8 10 12 
9 11 13 15 17 
14 16 18 20 22 24 
19 21 23 25 27 29 31 
26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 
33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49
```

If the length of each row matters, then the second for loop should have a different exit condition I suppose

Answer (score 0):

To get the pattern from 3 5 7, this code would do, where `MAX_PATTERN_NUM` is the first number of the last line of the pattern (in your example's case, `MAX_PATTERN_NUM = 15`)

```
 for(int i = 3; i <= MAX_PATTERN_NUM ; i+=3)
        for(int j = i; j <= (i + 4); j+=2)
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        System.out.println();
```

However, I see no logical way of getting the entire pattern using the same nested for loops, so I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public void printPattern(){

    int evenCounter = 2;
    int oddCounter = 1; //counters

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = kb.nextInt();
    while (num % 2 == 0 || num < 0) {
        num = kb.nextInt(); //input
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= num ; ++i){
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            evenCounter = addNumbers(i, evenCounter); //print line with evenCounter
        else
            oddCounter = addNumbers(i, oddCounter); //print line with oddCounter
    }
}

private int addNumbers(int i, int counter){
    for(int j = 0; j < i;){
        if(getIntLength(counter) + j > i) //if the number to long
            System.out.print(cut(counter, getIntLength(counter) + j - i) + " "); //output the cut version
        else
            System.out.print(counter + " ");
        j += getIntLength(counter);
        counter += 2;
    }
    System.out.println();
    return counter;
}

private String cut(int i, int length){
    return Integer.toString(i).substring(0,length); //get substring of int
}

private int getIntLength(int i){
    return Integer.toString(i).length(); //get the length of int value
}
```

It's not so simple, but I don't see an easier way

My answer is based on the assumption that the last 2 is a cut off 21

Answer (score -1):

```
int n,i,j,o=1,e=2;
System.out.println("enter n:");
n=sc.nextInt();
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++){

        if(i%2!=0){
            System.out.print(o);
            o+=2;
        }

        if(i%2==0){
            System.out.print(e);
            e+=2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You've missed the definition of sc here. Where is sc.nextInt coming from?